# How to run Flask on Windows Machine?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm running this code to train a dimple model and pickle the results:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\prices.csv')
df.head()

y = df['Value'] 
X = df[['Rooms', 'Distance']]


from sklearn import linear_model
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X, y)


lm.predict([[8.2,9]])


import pickle
pickle.dump(lm, open('C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\model.pkl','wb'))
```

Now, I open Anaconda Prompt, and run the file: `C:\Users\ryans\Desktop\app.py`.

Here's the app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\model.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    """Grabs the input values and uses them to make prediction"""
    rooms = int(request.form["rooms"])
    distance = int(request.form["distance"])
    prediction = model.predict([[rooms, distance]])  # this returns a list e.g. [127.20488798], so pick first element [0]
    output = round(prediction[0], 2) 

    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text=f'A house with {rooms} rooms and located {distance} meters from the city center has a value of ${output}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Desktop\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Flask is already installed, so I think it's some kind of issue like running Flask in a virtual environment, or whatever. This is my first time doing this kind of thing. How can I get Flask to run on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install flask? If you're running under the conda prompt, try running **conda install flask**. And then see if it allows you to run your application

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but it didn't work. Any other thoughts?

Comment: again a problem with virtual environments i guess